# What is the best way to run a scheduled task on Android even during deep sleep?

Tags: android, service, timer, background-process, timertask

I am working on my bachelor thesis and have encountered a problem.

**What I have:**

I've written an app that is supposed to measure sensor data from an external device. Therefore it should run over a long period of time.

In my `MainActivity` the user presses a button to start a `Service`. Inside the `Service` it create multiple `Timer`s and `TimerTask`s (one for each sensor). I store them in two separate `List`s. Each sensor has an own period that says how often it should get called. For example sensor1 gets called every 10sec and sensor2 every 5min. To achieve this I call

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(currentTask, 0, period);
```

for each `TimerTask` when the `Service` gets started.

In the `run()` method I call the sensor and save its value and a timestamp in the app's database.

**What the problem is:**

As long as the device is on, everything works perfectly fine. But as soon as the device goes to sleep it's really starting to act weird.

For example: I have one sensor scheduled to get values every 10sec. I press start and leave the device on for 30secs. This way I get 3 values every 10secs. Then I press power to put it in sleep mode for 1min and turn it on again. What I get are 6 values (as expected), but the timestamps don't fit. Between the last timestamp when the device was on and the first it went to sleep lie more than 10sec. The next few even have the same timestamp meaning the `run()` method was called multiple times within the same second. When I turn on the device every gets back to normal and works fine.

That means something isn't working correctly during sleep mode. I guess it **must** have something to do with the `TimerTask` and the `Timer`.

**Further important information:**

What can be ruled out (I guess):

- the way I call the system time (I even tried `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`, same problem)
- the device (I tested it on my Nexus 7 (2013) and a S3 Mini, on both it failed, **BUT** it worked on my Nexus 4 meaning that this one does not seem to go to sleep correctly, but that's another problem I guess)
- the external sensors (because I use a simulation instead meaning I create random values instead of calling real sensors just for testing)

Answer (score 0):

> I guess it must have something to do with the TimerTask and the Timer.

It's more that when the CPU is powered down, your code does not run.

*If* your device will always be plugged into a power source *and* you will always have a UI in the foreground, add `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to some widget in that UI, to keep the screen and CPU powered on.

Or, *if* your device will always be plugged into a power source, acquire your own `WakeLock` to keep the CPU powered on. This will require the `WAKE_LOCK` permission. This is *not* a suitable solution for a production app, but for some lab experiment (i.e., something you will not be shipping on the Play Store), it should be fine.

Or, *if* your device will *not* be plugged into a power source, replace your `Timer`, `TimerTask`, and `Service` with `AlarmManager` and either:

- [a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) and an `IntentService`, or
- a `BroadcastReceiver` and [my `WakefulIntentService`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

Those will wake up the device out of sleep mode and let you do a bit of work, before letting the device go to sleep again.

*However*, if you really plan on connecting to some external hardware, bear in mind that this approach may not work well, as the handshaking to connect the device to the external hardware again when the device wakes up out of sleep mode may take too long. In that case, you really need to ensure that the device always has power, so that you can go with the `WakeLock` approach.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! I thought a `Service` is designed for processes like mine. The thing is, I already published it in the Play Store. The app is supposed to run on the long term in the background without any UI in the foreground. Depending on the way the sensors are connected to the device (USB or BT) there is or there isn't an external power supply connected to the Android device. The weird thing is that it is working with my Nexus 4 (Stock rooted 4.3 without any mods). I guess I won't have enough time to fix this issue before my deadline ends.

Comment: @kaolick: "I thought a Service is designed for processes like mine" -- a `Service` does not keep the device awake.

Comment: Good to know! ;-) I implemented a little work-around. I added a switch in the app settings so that the user can decide whether to keep the CPU awake or not (default is OFF, of course). Also the user gets informed that this can drain the battery. I achieve this by using a wakelock that I set to `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. I know it's not the best way but under the given circumstances it is for me. After I finished my thesis I can implement a better solution.